# ScriptManager with ASP.NET Framework 2.0

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

I'm working on ASP.NET "Framework 2.0" and I'm not able to use ScriptManager control.
What should I do to be able to use ScriptManager and other AJAX extensions without updating to newer framework?

Comment: If you have the opportunity, you're better of using a javascript library (like jquery) to get friendly and powerful ajax functionnalities instead of using the ScriptManager and the heavy microsoft ajax framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should install [ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=883) and you will able to do things, you are used to.

Comment: But that link will not work for asp.net framework 2.0.  That is for 3.5+.

Comment: Initially I thought, that was the right link. I changed it, when you were writing your post :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find the 2.0 version on the asp.net website anymore.
For the 2.0 version they have archived this.
You will need the archived version found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=883)

Answer (score 0):

The working link is: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883

**ASP.NET AJAX 1.0**

ASP.NET AJAX is a set of technologies to add AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) support to ASP.NET. It consists of a client-side script framework, server controls, and more.